# How Do I Combine Property Files In Gradle?

Tags: gradle, ant

I have an ant task that combines 2 property files together to make a single properties file.

The `base.config` contains the majority of the properties and the `override.config` contains one or more properties that modifies the value in the `base.config`

```
<!--Combine the base.config and override.config together to create a properties file-->
<target name="generateProperties" depends="init">
    <property prefix="app.properties" file="override.config"/>
    <property prefix="app.properties" file="base.config"/>
    <echoproperties destfile="${build.dir}/combined.properties">
        <propertyset>
            <propertyref prefix="app.properties"/>
            <mapper type="glob" from="app.properties.*" to="*"/>
        </propertyset>
    </echoproperties>
</target>
```

How do I do the same thing in gradle (without importing the ant task)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [WriteProperties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.WriteProperties.html) task that can reliably save the properties.

You then just have to pass the Properties in a way that the base is overridden.

e.g.

```
task generateProperties(type: WriteProperties) {
    Properties combinedProperties = new Properties()
    File baseProperties = file('base.config')
    baseProperties.withInputStream {
        combinedProperties.load(it)
    }
    File overrideProperties = file('override.config')
    overrideProperties.withInputStream {
        combinedProperties.load(it)
    }
    properties = combinedProperties
    outputFile = file("$buildDir/combined.properties")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There are (5) property 'scopes' Gradle has for finding properties. They are:

- `Project` instance itself
- Extra properties
- Extensions
- Conventions
- Tasks
- Project parent (recursive lookup with the above)

You can read a more in-depth overview here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#properties

Gradle searches for properties in that order. So you can define base properties lower in the chain and provide overrides higher up in the chain.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.